# Problem with updating data in asp .NET MVC 2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i am just getting started with asp .NET MVC 2 applications and i stumbled upon a problem. I'm having trouble updating my tables. The debugger doesn't report any error, it just doesn't do anything... I hope some can help me out. Thank you for your time. 
This is my controller code...

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var supplierToEdit = (from c in _entities.SupplierSet
                              where c.SupplierId == id
                              select c).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(supplierToEdit);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Supplier/Edit/5

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Supplier supplierToEdit)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        try
        {
            var originalSupplier = (from c in _entities.SupplierSet
                                    where c.SupplierId == supplierToEdit.SupplierId
                                    select c).FirstOrDefault();

            _entities.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalSupplier.EntityKey.EntitySetName, supplierToEdit);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This is my View ...

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>



        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactTitle) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactTitle) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactTitle) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.City) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostalCode) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fax) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fax) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fax) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomePage) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HomePage) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomePage) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Comment: what is null? _entities or originalSupplier? Does your SupplierId  still have the right value?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are getting an exception. Try to throw the exeception in the Try catch statement

```
try
{
    var originalSupplier = (from c in _entities.SupplierSet
                            where c.SupplierId == supplierToEdit.SupplierId
                            select c).FirstOrDefault();

    _entities.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalSupplier.EntityKey.EntitySetName, supplierToEdit);
    _entities.SaveChanges();
    // TODO: Add update logic here

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
    return View();
}
```

Because i think its something underlaying.

Comment: It trows an exeception -
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 95:             catch(Exception ex)
Line 96:             {
Line 97:                 throw ex;
Line 98:                 return View();
Line 99:             }

p.s. i'm new with asp .NET also

Answer (score 0):

I'll Hazard a guess and say that your `_entities` variable is null at the time you're trying to fire off the `ApplyPropertyChanges` method.

This would cause a

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

error to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
  public ActionResult Edit(Supplier supplierToEdit)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    try
    {
        var originalSupplier = (from c in _entities.SupplierSet
                                where c.SupplierId == supplierToEdit.SupplierId
                                select c).FirstOrDefault();
  _entities.UpdateModel(originalSupplier);
        _entities.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalSupplier.EntityKey.EntitySetName, supplierToEdit);
        _entities.SaveChanges();
        // TODO: Add update logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```